# How to make divs auto fit themselves to the height of the window

Tags: html, css

I'm having problem with making a div stretch and shrink depending on the size of the browser.

Here is the html

```
<div class="content_container">
    <div class="content_menu"></div>
    <div class="content_left"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>


.content_container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:100vh;
    display:block;  
}
.content_left{
    background: #eee none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    height:calc(100vh - 50px);
}
.content_menu{
    background: #eee none repeat scroll 0 0;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 25%;
    height:100vh;
}
.content{
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50%;
}
```

I've already tried giving `height:auto`, 100% and 100vh but none seems to work.

The `.content_left` and `.content_menu` fall short of the height of the `.content` so there are blank white spaces.

Is there anyway those layers can resize themselves to fit to the height as well as the `.content` div.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: So basically you're saying you want to get rid of the vertical scrollbar and have divs fit size of viewport at all times?

Comment: um, @Michael_B not really.that's not what i meant. there's no way getting rid of the vertical scrollbar on the site i gave you, as the contents are probably more than 100% size. i merely want to have .content_left and .content_menu to stretch their height to fit to the browser height.

Comment: Didn't visit your site. I was working off of the code in your question, which is supposed to reproduce the problem. Vertical scrollbar can be eliminated with `body { margin: 0; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `viewport width/height` to set an elements dimensions **relative** to the **window**

```css
body {
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
}
div {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#two {
  width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
}
#one {
  width: 60%;
  width: 60vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">div one</div>
<div id="two">div two</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the blank white spaces you are talking about are those surrounding the gray elements on the left and right side. Those are caused by the default margin on the body. Just set the body margin to zero.

`body { margin: 0; }`

Using your markup in your question, it appears to work as I think you want it to.